# WCF customBinding problem

Tags: wcf

I've been playing around with a pollingDuplex example that is driving me nuts. I'm using a customBinding to integrate the readerQuotas element and I keep getting the error: "Contract requires Duplex, but binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it."
Where is that BasicHttpBinding coming from when I am using customBinding ? I've checked countless examples and my configuration file matches what they had but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this ?
Thanks.

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>

<extensions>
  <bindingElementExtensions>
    <add name="pollingDuplex" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.PollingDuplexElement, System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex"/>
  </bindingElementExtensions>
</extensions>

<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="DBNotification" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <httpsTransport maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
      <pollingDuplex duplexMode="MultipleMessagesPerPoll" maxPendingSessions="2147483647" maxPendingMessagesPerSession="2147483647"/>
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="AdminWebService" behaviorConfiguration="DBNotificationServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="adminservice" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="DBNotification" contract="AdminWebService.IAdminWebService" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>      
    <behavior name="DBNotificationServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the case, but can you try in your custom binding change the order of the elements such that the transport is the last one (i.e., `<pollingDuplex/>`, `<binaryMessageEncoding/>` then `<httpsTransport/>`)? IIRC when you're using code to create a custom binding this order is enforced.

Comment: Nope, same thing. It's like it's checking another web.config file in an alternate universe somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably running into the "simplified configuration" problem - described in details at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2009/11/09/common-user-mistake-in-net-4-mistyping-the-service-configuration-name.aspx. The "name" attribute in the `<service>` element must be the **fully-qualified name** of the service. Since your interface is `AdminWebService.IAdminWebService`, isn't your service name `AdminWebService.AdminWebService`? If so, fixing the name attribute should fix the issue.

Comment: Damn that was it. I actually read that issue but didn't spot it in my configuration. What mislead me was that the same configuration worked perfectly when I was using a simple [ServiceContract] but once I turned it into [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IDuplexClient))] to implement the client callback the error popped up. Thanks a lot ! I was driving myself nuts trying to figure that one out.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that `httpGetEnabled="true"` implies using `BasicHttpBinding`? Do you really need this feature? Does the error goes away if you comment this line?

Comment: I thought about that too. Tried commenting it out and setting it to false. Same thing. Still converts to BasicHttpBinding somehow.

Comment: @algorunescu: can you provide your custom binding implementation then?